# Strunk & White badge - possible bug

Tags: support, edits, badges, badge-progress

I am not sure if this is the correct place to post it, but here we go:

I noticed my steps for earning the [Strunk & White badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) have not moved for quite a while. I think it might be because I crossed the 2K reputation and earned the "edit questions and answers" privilege (edit to any question and answer is applied immediately.

Is this a bug maybe? Or should we increase the counter for "Strunk & White" and ["Copy Editor"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) badges?

Comment: Do you have examples of recent edits that should count and you're not seeing increase the counter? It could be a bug, a cache issue, or you missing something with the criteria for the badge. (That last one happens a decent amount for several badges.)

Comment: Also, getting the 2k privilege makes it _easier_ to get the editing badges.  Now your edits don't have to be reviewed before approval.  They are applied immediately.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. When did you notice the counter wasn't increasing? Last month? This month?

Comment: @Kendra too many tag-only edits?  [Tag-only edits don't count towards these badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Exactly what I think it is.

Comment: Funk & Wagnalls to it.

Comment: Here is a full reference for badges and what it takes to get them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at your list of edits on your profile, I see what I believe to be the cause of your issue.

Your last few edits don't count for the badge. Tag only edits, or edits that only change the tags of a question, *do not* count for the badge. The last edit you made that counted for the badge was a tag wiki edit on March 11th for the keystone tag.

From the [MSE FAQ post*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732) outlining the full badge details:

> **Strunk & White**
>
> - silver;
> - awarded once Perform a total of 80 edits between questions, answers, and tag wikis
>
> (...)
>
> **Additional criteria for this
>   badge family (excluding Editor):**
>
> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to community wiki posts **do** count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits **do** count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

(Emphasis original)

---

<sub>* The link leads directly to the "Moderation badges" answer, the relevant answer for this badge.</sub>

Comment: Hum ... that explains. Some of my tag edits had tag changes. Thanks Kendra!